# How to write CSS expression to click on "Select " i have tried with different x path its not working in IE any version

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
  <div class="row-fluid">
  <table class="s-table table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
  <thead class="p-table-head">
  <tbody class="p-table-body">
  <tr>
  <td>
  <td>
  <td>
  <td>
  <td>
  <td>
  <td>
  <td>
  <td>
  <td>
  <div id="div_2_1_2_1_1_1_10_r9" class="Action_Group CoachView CoachView_show" data- eventid="" data-viewid="Action_Group1" data-config="config_div_2_1_2_1_1_1_10_r9" data-bindingtype="" data-binding="" data-type="com.ibm.bpm.coach.Snapshot_9e739df9_ccc7_4dfa_9b75_8233150ad5bc.Action_Group">
  <div id="div_2_1_2_1_1_1_10_1_r9" class="ContentBox" data-view-managed="true" style="display: none;"> </div>
  <div class="s-action-group clearfix">
  <div class="l-nodeId" style=" display: none; "></div>
  <div class="p-action-group">
  <div id="div_2_1_2_1_1_1_10_1_1_r9" class="Action CoachView CoachView_show" data-      eventid="boundaryEvent_10" data-viewid="Action3" data-config="config_div_2_1_2_1_1_1_10_1_1_r9" data-bindingtype="" data-binding="" data-type="com.ibm.bpm.coach.Snapshot_9e739df9_ccc7_4dfa_9b75_8233150ad5bc.Action" style="background-color: transparent;">
 <button id="div_2_1_2_1_1_1_10_1_1_r9-lnk" type="button" style="display: none;">
<a class="p-action-link" href="#action" title="">
 <i style="display: none;"></i>
<span style="background-color: transparent;">Select</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I have tried with the following different x path expression its works fine in Firefox but in IE browser it is not working?.

```
//tbody[@class='p-table-body']/tr/td[10]/div/div/div/div/a/span

//table[@class='s-table table table-bordered table-striped table-  hover']/tbody/tr[1]/td[10]/div/div/div[2]/div/a/span

//*[@id='div_2_1_2_1_1_1_10_1_1_r9']/a/span
```

Note : i have tried to execute scripts it is not fail but main issue it is not recognizing
select link of a customer.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Inside a table i want to click on **Select** link

Comment: The link you're trying to click has the style `display: none;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//*[@id='div_2_1_2_1_1_1_10_1_1_r9-lnk']/a/span
```

to click on select

Comment: I have tried with above x path but it is not working. Inside a table i need to click on **Select** link could you please let me know any other solution to handle it

Comment: u posted `div_2_1_2_1_1_1_10_1_1_r9` but u missed out `-lnk` at the end. plz check, if not update the question

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it can help, but try selecting just the 'a' element, instead. There's no need to select also the span element, as far as I can understand. E.g.:

```
By.cssSelector("#div_2_1_2_1_1_1_10_1_1_r9 a.p-action-link")
```

Also, a couple of recommendations.

1. Try to avoid xpath selectors, and write css selectors instead. See [selenium-docs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-docs/blob/master/start.rst#tips-on-using-selectors)
2. While writing a selector, you should not be too strict. "/tr/td[10]/div/div/div/div" is considered bad practice.
   See [Writing reliable locators for Selenium and WebDriver tests](http://blog.mozilla.org/webqa/2013/09/26/writing-reliable-locators-for-selenium-and-webdriver-tests/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to identify the element by using the text identifier

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/span[text()='Select']")).click();
```